# React Native: unexpected token

Tags: react-native

I am currently developing a app and I want my code can determine if current platform whether iPhone X or not. Here is my code.

```
function isiPhoneX() {
    let dimen = Dimensions.get('window');
    if (
        Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
        !Platform.isPad &&
        !Platform.isTVOS &&
        (dimen.height === 812 || dimen.width === 812)
    )
    return true;
}
export default TabNavigator({},{
isiPhoneX()===true?(
      tabBarOptions:{
        style: {
          height: 70,
          paddingBottom:  20,
        }
      }
    ):
    (tabBarOptions:{
      style: {
        height: 70,
        paddingBottom:  20,
      }
    });
},
);
```

and the Error message is SyntaxError /path/path/: Unexpected Token, expected {.
I am not sure why I have that syntax error, and how to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition should be outside the curly braces, and the objects should be properly enclosed between curly braces.
Try with something like this.

```
export default TabNavigator({}, isiPhoneX()===true ? 
{
  tabBarOptions:{
    style: {
      height: 70,
      paddingBottom:  20,
    }
  }
} :
{
  tabBarOptions: {
    style: {
      height: 70,
      paddingBottom:  20,
    }
  }
});
```

In the other hand, I don't see the point of the condition when both objects are identical.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return an object but it doesn't have wrapping curly braces

```
tabBarOptions: {
  style: {
    height: 70,
    paddingBottom: 20,
  }
}
```

should be

```
{
  tabBarOptions: {
    style: {
      height: 70,
      paddingBottom: 20,
    }
  }
}
```

and the second one as well.